# I need a word for "impotent whining"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word for the act of impotently whining and crying over something that you can't change —like, for example, moaning and groaning about what to do now that Trump is President-Elect instead of finding something actually useful to do.

Comment: The term *whining* covers it *per se. Impotent* whining would be pleonasm.

Comment: @BrianDonovan, yes, I know, but for whatever reason I didn't like "whining".  I was writing something for publication and "whining" wasn't a good choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"Hand-wringing"** is used to express the idea that someone is "fretting" over something and instead of taking positive action, just stands by, impotently wringing their hands.

[Hand-wringing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hand%E2%80%93wringing) as defined by MWO:

> an overwrought expression of concern or guilt

This expression dates back to 1922 (per MWO).

Answer (score 3):

I think the word **moping** works.

[**Mope**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mope):

> To be unhappy and unwilling to think or act in a positive way, especially because of a disappointment.
>
> 'There's no point in sitting at home and moping - get out there and find yourself another job!' (Cambridge Dictionary)
>
> ‘But he frequently has been his own worst enemy by moping and overanalyzing, leading to a loss of confidence and bad habits.’ [(OED)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mope)

Answer (score 1):

There's always the British "whinging," which I think of as "extra-strength whining". (Also, with respect to the Trunp presidency, I think "grieving" may be what you're observing in others.

Comment: No, it's definitely "whinging".  I know what grieving looks like, and I can commiserate with it.  The Trump-whinger people are too pathetic to commiserate with.  +1 for "extra-strength whining"!

Answer (score 1):

Of course *bleating* comes from the sound of a sheep or a goat, but it has come to mean a feeble whining, which is pretty close to an impotent whining. The Free Dictionary: bleating ". 2. A whining, feeble complaint."